# Extended ASCII characters changed upon opening Vim in different shell

Tags: microsoft-windows, bash

Specifically, I have encountered this issue with the *lowercase a* with an umlaut ä and the lowercase *scharfes s* ß. Their (extended) ASCII values are `0xDF` and `0xE4`, respectively:

[image: (extended) ASCII table with the relevant characters highlighted]

This can be [seen](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Showing_the_ASCII_value_of_the_current_character), in the lower left corner, by invoking

```
:set statusline=%<%f%h%m%r%=%b\ 0x%B\ \ %l,%c%V\ %P
```

I insert the characters in one [git-bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) terminal shell, and both characters look the same upon opening the file again (in the same shell):

[image: Opened in the same shell, characters show no change screenshot]

When I open the same file in a different shell, the two characters are changed to `Ã¤d` and `Ã~_` , respectively. In the second case `Ã~_`, however, Vim points out that `~_` is actually the character `Ÿ`; since it recognizes it as the `0x9F` (extended) ASCII character:

[image: Bad digraphs in different shell example screenshot]

I have this same issue with many other extended ASCII characters. Does anybody know what causes these characters to change upon saving and opening in a different shell?

Comment: check your encoding setting

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Are you saying that there is an encoding "mismatch" between the output of the terminal and Vim's encoding setting? What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @ChristianBrabandt, the issue with my minimal working example (MWE, in the post) was solved by changing my encoding to *utf-8*:

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

However, in my original file, the characters were still displayed incorrectly, even after changing the encoding setting. I had to manually re-insert the characters. Not sure why it worked straight away with my MWE, but not with my original file.

Comment: Vim converts unrecognized characters automatically. Check +bad on the help.